# Getting distinct SelectListItem

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, linq-to-objects

I am using Linq to get only unique member of a select List item.  How do I return a this list...
What I have now is

```
    var queryResult = PatientList.Select(c => c).Distinct();
    PatientList = (List<SelectListItem>)queryResult;
```

I am getting a cast error on the second line.  What should an enterprising young developer do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
PatientList = queryResult.ToList();
```

You version uses casting, which is impossible in this case, as the query result is not a list. `ToList` constructs a new list, basing on the enumerable against which it is called. It does something like this:

```
public static List<T> ToList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection)
{
    return new List<T>(collection);
}
```

You must be sure, obviously, that `PatientList` elements are of type `SelectListItem` and be aware that `Distinct()` will return the different OBJECTS, but not items with different fields. I.e., if in `PatientList` you have two independently constructed items with equal `Selected`, `Text` and `Value` properties, you will still have two as a result of the `Distinct()` call.

Additionally, what is the reason to use `Select(c => c)`? It effectively does noting.

Comment: I am a Linq noob.  I am finding out it is very useful, that being said.
When I remove it, I get a compiler error.

Comment: It appears as though I am not getting just distinct SelectListItems

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know what type are the item in your list but for what you have posted you can call `Distinct()` directly on the list

```
  List<int> ages = new List<int> { 21, 46, 46, 55, 17, 21, 55, 55 };

    IEnumerable<int> distinctAges = ages.Distinct();
```

Adding `.ToList()` if you need to convert it to a List